# How to have Items from a ListView have different padding in Flutter?

Tags: flutter

I have a simple `Listview` builder that returns a `ItemsItem` with a Container in it. 
I would like the last `Item` to have a bottom padding.

I could check if the `index` from the `items` is the last one, and give that to the `ItemsItem` but the problem is that the padding on the Container needs to be a `const`

any ideas?

```
...
new ListView.builder(
    itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) => new ItemsItem(item: items[index]),
    itemCount: items.length,
)
...



// if this is the last Item, add a padding to the Container
class ItemsItem extends StatefulWidget {
...

    return new Container();
```

Comment: The padding on a container _doesn't_ need to be const, it just _can_ be const.  This is a perfectly reasonable case to use new instead

Comment: Padding does not require `const`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
  bool last = items.length == (index + 1);
  return new Container(
    padding: last ? yourEdgeInsets : null,
    child: new ItemsItem(item: items[index]),
  );
}
```

Comment: dammit. I was setting the padding like this `const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: length)` thank you